# conditional sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables where depending on a value on the first one, i have to select a column on the second one.

Example

table1

```
data1|data2|type
P3   | C   |  R
P1   | D   |  N
P2   | C   |  R
P1   | C   |  N
P2   | D   |  R
P3   | D   |  N
```

table2

```
name|revolution|nibs
C   |repeat    |may
D   |genocide  |fill
```

So, I want to get the values for data1 according to the type as this (R for revolution, N for nibs)

Querying for P3:

```
name|value
C   |repeat
D   |fill
```

Querying for P1

```
name|value
C   |may
D   |fill
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.name,  IF(t1.type='R',t2.revolution,t2.nibs) as value 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.data2 = t2.name
WHERE t1.data1 = ?
```

Comment: Your first answer was wrong (previous the edit) but I managed to get it and we've reached the same result, so thanks :D

Comment: @Diego Yep, missed the join condition:)

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach to this is to use a CASE:

```
select 
    t1.data2,
    case t1.type
        when 'R' then t2.revolution
        when 'N' then t2.nibs
    end
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.data2 = t2.name
where data1 = ?
```